# How to add tooltip on image using primefaces

Tags: primefaces, xhtml, tooltip

Below is the code i tried and its not working.

```
<p:column>
<img border="0" src="../images/xxx.png"id="stage1" 
     alt="xxxx" width="300" height="106"></img>
<p:tooltip for="stage1" showEffect="blind" hideEffect="explode" showEvent="mouseover" hideEvent="mouseout"> 
xxxxxxxx
</p:tooltip>
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a `p:tooltip` with an image, you have to use a `p:graphicImage` to load your image, not an `img` tag (happened to me quite a few times with PF 4.0). If your `p:tooltip` displays only text, it would be better to use a `value` attribute: the HTML generated is less... "bulky". Note that the default `showEvent` is "mouseover" and default `hideEvent` is "mouseOut".

```
<p:column>
  <p:graphicImage id="stage1" value="images/xxx.png" alt="xxxx" 
                 style="border:0; width:300px; height:106px;"/>
  <p:tooltip for="stage1" showEffect="blind" hideEffect="explode" value="xxxxxxxx"/> 
</p:column>
```

Comment: Ya i figured it out same day, any ways thank you for posting the answer

Answer (score -3):

I think you have it almost right

```
<p:column>
<img border="0" src="../images/xxx.png"id="stage1" 
     alt="xxxx" width="300" height="106"></img>
<pe:tooltip for="stage1" showEffect="blind" hideEffect="explode" showEvent="mouseover" hideEvent="mouseout"> 
xxxxxxxx
</pe:tooltip>
</p:column>
```

It is `pe:tooltip` not `p:tooltip`

Comment: according to showcase `<p:tooltip>` seems also correct. Look here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/tooltip/tooltipOptions.xhtml

Comment: Please test your theory before submitting the answer, pe namespace is for prime-extensions .. This is related to primefaces not the extensions